# django model_to_dict including foreignkeys pointing to model

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I have a model:

```
class Main(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=99)
```

Which has multiple inlines:

```
class First(models.Model):
    Main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Second(models.Model):
    Main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm trying to send a specific object "main" with all of it's inlines (First and Second). But whenever I do:

```
'main': model_to_dict(main)
```

It will only pass the "name" value from within the Main class, and it will ignore all the inline values.

I've looked at a few other questions similar to this and tried their solutions but unfortunately changing it to:

```
'main': main.__dict__
```

doesn't work.

I tried my own model_to_dict here:

```
def model_to_dict(instance, include=None, exclude=None):
    fields = instance._meta.concrete_fields
    if include is not None:
        return {f.attname: getattr(instance, f.attname) for f in fields if f.name in include}
    if exclude is not None:
        return {f.attname: getattr(instance, f.attname) for f in fields if f.name not in exclude}
    return {f.attname: getattr(instance, f.attname) for f in fields}
```

Also didn't pass the inlines.

Is there any easy way to pass these through a JsonResponse? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think you have to call the First and Second classes separately from the parent class. Like:

`dict = model_to_dict(main.First)`

Then add it to the dictionary containing the parent model's json.

Or, even better, you could even customize the model_to_dict method to handle the inlines, I guess.